Ornstein-Uhlenbeck parameters and correlation function
I am new learning an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (O-U) process $x(t)$. I understood that the process follows the following stochastic differential equation:
$$dx(t) = -\theta x(t) + \sigma dW(t),$$
when the mean is $0$ and $W(t)$ is the Wiener process. I am trying to understand these parameters $\theta$ and $\sigma$. Specifically, if I'm given the correlation function in the following form:
$$ \langle x(t) x(0) \rangle = b^2 e^{-t/T},$$
what are the values of $\theta, \sigma$? Based on my shallow intuition, since the process decays exponential with time over $T$ and $b$ more or less represents the strength of the random fluctuation, it seems like we have $\theta = T, \sigma = b$. Happy to be corrected and would like to learn more!

Is $x_0$ distributed as the stationary measure?

It is is not true that the process following that SDE is a Gaussian process with correlation function $\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}e^{-\theta|t-s|}$ but there is a relationship.

@Snoop yes it is.

Snoop's correct answer shows that the "correlation function" you have to use is $\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$ which is physicists notation for $E[x_tx_0],.$ A mathematician however considers $E[x_tx_0]-E[x_t]E[x_0]$ as the covariance function and $$\frac{E[x_tx_0]-E[x_t]E[x_0]}{\sqrt{E[x_t^2]-E[x_t]^2}\sqrt{E[x_0^2]-E[x_0]^2}}$$ as the correlation function. Lots of things to watch out for and related to the link I gave above.

@KurtG. Thank you for your clarification, it's now clear to me!

I guess $x_0\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta})$ which is the stationary measure of $dx_t=-\theta x_tdt+\sigma dW_t$. We have $E[x_t|x_0]=x_0e^{-\theta t}$ so $E[x_tx_0]=E[E[x_t|x_0]x_0]=E[x_0^2e^{-\theta t}]=e^{-\theta t}E[x_0^2]=e^{-\theta t}\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}$ so $T=1/\theta$ and $b=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\theta}}$.

Thank you! I realize this is a bit late, but I have a follow-up question: if$x_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta})$ where $\mu \neq 0$, what would happen in this case? Can we still treat the process as an O-U process and analyze the dynamics with this modified initial condition (with the same correlation function, parameters, etc)?

@mike you are welcome. In that case, I would say that we would have $E[x_0^2]=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}+\mu^2$, so $T=1/\theta$ and $b=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}+\mu^2}$. If you are given the values $b,T$, you would also need to know $\mu$ to solve for $\sigma$. The process is still O-U, so $E[x_t|x_0]$ does not change. However, $E[x_t x_0]$ indeed changes.

Yes, that makes sense, thank you. I was actually thinking more about the case where $b$ and $\mu$ are independent variables. For example, I fix $b, T$ and examine the same process, but assume that the initial point $x_0$ is sampled from a non-stationary distribution like $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \cdot)$ for different values of $\mu$. Then, for example, I am trying to see if we have $E(x_t) = E(x_0)e^{-\theta t} = \mu e^{-\theta t}$ using numerical simulations. But then I started to wonder if this process is still a valid O-U process or not.

@mike If $x_0$ is random, but 'known at time $0$' and has finite variance, then the process is still a O-U process (in the sense that the SDE has the usual unique solution). Its unconditional mean is indeed $E[x_t]=E[E[x_t|x_0]]=e^{-\theta t}E[x_0]=e^{-\theta t}\mu$. If you want technical details, this would deserve its own question.
